# java.io.FileNotFoundException while creating Bitmap from a File Object on Android

Tags: java, android

I get an Object containing a File:

```
public class Ordo implements java.io.Serializable{

static final long serialVersionUID = 11223344;

public String id;
public String name;
public String date;
public String status;
public File thumbnail;
```

and I need to convert this File into a Bitmap to be viewed on an Activity.
I'm doing the following:

```
thumbnail = list.getFileFromId(vid);
    Bitmap pic = null;
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int bytesRead;
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(thumbnail);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        while((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1){
            stream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        pic = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(stream.toByteArray(), 0,    stream.size());
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but I get the following error:

> 04-28 18:16:16.759: W/System.err(31995): java.io.FileNotFoundException: 1461854326445.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>   04-28 18:16:16.779: W/System.err(31995):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
>   04-28 18:16:16.779: W/System.err(31995):    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:76)
>   04-28 18:16:16.779: W/System.err(31995):    at com.jre.link.View.onCreate(ViewOrdo.java:83)
>   04-28 18:16:16.779: W/System.err(31995):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
>   04-28 18:16:16.779: W/System.err(31995):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
>   04-28 18:16:16.779: W/System.err(31995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
>   04-28 18:16:16.779: W/System.err(31995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
>   04-28 18:16:16.779: W/System.err(31995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
>   04-28 18:16:16.779: W/System.err(31995):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
>   04-28 18:16:16.779: W/System.err(31995):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   04-28 18:16:16.779: W/System.err(31995):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>   04-28 18:16:16.779: W/System.err(31995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
>   04-28 18:16:16.779: W/System.err(31995):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   04-28 18:16:16.779: W/System.err(31995):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   04-28 18:16:16.779: W/System.err(31995):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>   04-28 18:16:16.779: W/System.err(31995):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

it seems that I need to create a physical file from my File Object...
any idea how I can solve that ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Where are you saving your file? Update with that code. Also have you added proper permissions in manifest?

Comment: Do not use a byte array output stream but directly use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thumbnail);`

Comment: What is the value of thumbnail.getAbsolutePath()?

Comment: my file is not saved physically on the hard drive, it is sent by the server in a Java Object but may be this is not the simpliest way...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I'll try to find another way by including a Bitmap instead of a File in my Object....it will be easier. thanks for your answers anyway.